# Converting a list to Dictionary in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings.
I want to create a Dictionary of string, string, with "Id" as the key for each entry and the contents of the list as the value.

i.e.

```
myList= { "string1", "string2", ...etc }
```

and therefore

```
myDictionary = {{"Id1", "string1"}, {"Id2", "string2"}, ...etc}
```

I have been trying to create a dictionary using the List.ToDictionary method but to no avail

```
List.ToDictionary(Of String, String)("Id", Function(p) p.key)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
  Dim list As List(of string)
  Dim dict As IDictionary(Of String) = list.ToDictionary(Function(p) "Id", Function(p) p)
```

Comment: maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't "p" in that expression of type String?

Comment: It is. Also, the OP has asked for _all_ keys to be "Id" which sorta breaks the idea of a dictionary...

Comment: Yes. and string does not have a Key, nor a Value members

Comment: except you can't have a dictionary with duplicate keys.

Comment: @hometoast Yes I agree and I am considering that OP knows this fact and has missed to mention it!!! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: As an answer to create a dictionary from list, this is it, even though you would replace "Id" with something more meaningful. As far as OP formulated the question - well, it's another story. +1 for the approach.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to create a Dictionary of string, string, with "Id" as the key
>   for each entry

This is impossible. Every entry in the dictionary must have a unique key.

Comment: :- I think OP knows this point. He has just missed to mention it. I have just considered it like that ;)